# Popup Message if not the specific user

Tags: cakephp

```
function beforeFilter() {
if($this->Session->read('Users.username') == 'budiman' or $this->Session-    >read('Users.username') == 'john' ){
$this->Auth->allow('*');
} else {            
//$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
}
}
```

this is my code.
what I want if user is not budiman or john,
it will popup some message, can it be done.?

Answer (score 0):

To popup during the load?
You can't  - this code must finish the execution before it is displayed